# VBA Code to create and name new sheet based on variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my code to add a sheet with the name the code determines based on the Function_Name variable. When I run this it names the new sheet Function_Name. Any thoughts?

```
For X = 1 To B
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Function_Name = Range("B2").Offset(X, 0)   'Gets the Function Name
    Worksheets.Add().Name = ("Function_Name")
Next X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For X = 1 To B
    Worksheets.Add().Name = Sheets("Calculations").Range("B2").Offset(X, 0).Value
Next X
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, you have Function_Name in quotes in

```
Worksheets.Add().Name = ("Function_Name")
```

The quotes should be removed.

Tim's answer gives an even more succinct way of writing the code.

You may also consider putting in some error trapping because if you try and add a worksheet with a name that already exists, you will get a run time error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wksSource   as worksheet

For X = 1 To B
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Function_Name = Range("B2").Offset(X, 0)   'Gets the Function Name
    Set wksSource = worksheets.add
    wksSource.Name = ("Function_Name")
    Set wksSource = nothing
Next X
```